# Building apk file with buildozer error Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy, buildozer

I'm making an apk from python and kivy for the first time so if this is some newbie question sorry.

I want to build app for android from python and kivy scrips using buildozer tool. After few newbie errors like I didn't install javac etc., this error occurred:

```
 Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "carlockapp"
```

Additional info:
OS: Fedora 22 32bit

```
[agi@localhost CarLockApp]$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
/bin/sh: dpkg: command not found
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-14.b27.fc22.i386/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-14.b27.fc22.i386/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/agi/Documents/CarLockApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
which: no virtualenv-2.7 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no virtualenv2.7 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no virtualenv2 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no cython2 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws wokkel zeroconf zope
# Application requirements already installed, pass
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/agi/Documents/CarLockApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
which: no virtualenv-2.7 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no virtualenv2.7 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no virtualenv2 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no cython2 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws wokkel zeroconf zope
# Clean and build python-for-android
# Remove directory and subdirectory /home/agi/Documents/CarLockApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/carlockapp
# Run './distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "carlockapp"'
# Cwd /home/agi/Documents/CarLockApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
which: no virtualenv-2.7 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no virtualenv2.7 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no virtualenv2 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
which: no cython2 in (/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin)
./distribute.sh: line 286: lsb_release: command not found
Check build dependencies for 
Avoid check build dependencies, unknow platform 
Check environment
SDK located at /home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
NDK located at /home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
NDK version is r9c
API level set to 14
Check NDK location
Check mandatory tools
Distribution will be located at /home/agi/Documents/CarLockApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/carlockapp
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
PATH is /home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c:/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools:/home/agi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/agi/.local/bin:/home/agi/bin
Leaving ARM environment
Read kivy recipe
Module kivy depend on pygame pyjnius android
Read pygame recipe
Module pygame depend on python sdl
Read pyjnius recipe
Module pyjnius depend on python sdl
Read android recipe
Module android depend on pygame
Read python recipe
Module python depend on hostpython
Read sdl recipe
Module sdl depend on python
Ignored python, already processed
Ignored sdl, already processed
Ignored pygame, already processed
Read hostpython recipe
Ignored python, already processed
Modules changed to hostpython python sdl pygame pyjnius android kivy
Pure-Python modules changed to 
Run get packages
Download package for hostpython
Module hostpython already downloaded
Download package for python
Module python already downloaded
Download package for sdl
No package for sdl
Download package for pygame
Module pygame already downloaded
Download package for pyjnius
Module pyjnius already downloaded
Download package for android
No package for android
Download package for kivy
Module kivy already downloaded
Run prebuild
Call prebuild_hostpython
Call prebuild_python
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "carlockapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: If you haven't already, change the log_level to 2(it's in the buildozer.spec file), like it says in the error. Then, running it again should give a more verbose error output.

Comment: Tnx, I did it already and this is whole output

Comment: Try using the command buildozer --verbose android debug

Comment: Tnx, I did it but nothing changed

Comment: here is the latest output https://db.tt/0XlK1ptP

Comment: If it's different, can you include it in your post.

Comment: have you tried `buildozer android clean`? if not try this and debug again

Comment: tnx, but it still returns the same error